# SQL Server INSERT INTO using EXECUTE

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, sql-insert

I am trying to insert a few values into a table using `EXECUTE` statement.

I have found few examples, however, those does not answer my question.

**Note:** sources given below are code from the procedure. All mentioned variables was declared and initialized.

First way I tried:

```sql
INSERT INTO [master].[dbo].[table_1] (column1, column2)
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@object id INT, @crlf CHAR(2)', @object_id, @crlf, 1
```

results in:

> Error: Procedure or function  has too many arguments specified.

And I completely understand why I am getting this. Because `sp_executesql` does not allow to have more than 4 arguments, and it cannot recognise which goes where.

Second try (where I only want to get the output using execute statement into the variable, and then put that into the table):

```sql
DECLARE @sql_in nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @sql_out nvarchar(max)
SET @sql_in = @sql + ',' 
    + N'@object_id INT, @crlf CHAR(2),' 
    + CONVERT(varchar(100), @object_id) + ',' + @crlf
PRINT @sql_in
EXEC sp_executesql @sql_in, N'@sql_out nvarchar(max) out', @sql_out out
```

And I get:

> Must declare scalar variable "@crlf"

and actually this variable is declared in the top of this procedure, but this one is not that clear for me, why it still complains...

What would be the most sufficient way to get the execution statement and the number(additional value) into the table?

Comment: in second portion and in declaration portion , you not define @crlf..that why error come. ok. Are you want insert with output of exec , right?

Comment: @Ajay2707, please do not most code as images.

Comment: sorry for not enough information that I have provided. all this code is in the stored procedure and the variable `@crlf` is declared in the top of it. And that's why it confuses me...

Answer (score 0):

As an only workaround I can suggest using a temporary table. Should be quite simple:

```
SELECT TOP (0) column1
INTO #TemporaryResults
FROM [master].[dbo].[table_1];

INSERT INTO #TemporaryResults
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@object_id INT, @crlf CHAR(2)', @object_id, @crlf;

INSERT INTO [master].[dbo].[table_1] (column1, column2)
SELECT column1, 1
FROM #TemporaryResults;
```

1. Create a copy of column1 from [table_1] column1
2. Insert records, produced by SP into it
3. Insert records to actual table

Answer (score 0):

Please try according with following example

```
DECLARE @IntVariable int;
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @max_title varchar(30);

SET @IntVariable = 197;
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @max_titleOUT = max(JobTitle) 
   FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee
   WHERE BusinessEntityID = @level';
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@level tinyint, @max_titleOUT varchar(30) OUTPUT';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @level = @IntVariable, @max_titleOUT=@max_title OUTPUT;
SELECT @max_title;
```

OBSERVATION

1. SQL query needs a parameter `@level` that is why we have declare it as parameter
2. again the SQL query returns the output at @max_titleOUT. So we also have declare it as parameter. so the final parameter list is

   ```
   SET @ParmDefinition = N'@level tinyint, @max_titleOUT varchar(30) OUTPUT';
   ```
3. now we have to send the `@level` value to dynamic query that's why we use `@level = @IntVariable` that sends the `@IntVariable` value to `@level`
4. Finally by `@max_titleOUT = @max_title OUTPUT` we take the output of dynamic query that saves at `@max_titleOUT`, copy the value to `@max_title`